# Inline matplotlib plot inside Pycharm Console

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pycharm, jupyter

I would like to have `inline matplotlib` plot in the Python Console of Pycharm.
To do that, I try to load a `Jupyter Console` instead of the `Standard Python console`. I try to add some `interpreters options` but obviously no change occurs.

Do you know a way to achieve it ?

**Pycharm standard console :**

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 29 2016, 14:26:21)     [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.3 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
PyDev console: using IPython 4.0.3
```

**Jupyter console :** [command: ipython qtconsole]

```
Jupyter QtConsole 4.1.1
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 29 2016, 14:26:21) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.3 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
%guiref   -> A brief reference about the graphical user interface.
```